# How To Remove The White Bar/nav from top of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

OK So Im almost done with the coding of my site and I cant seem to remove this white space from the top of my page is there anyway I can remove it or make it transparent so that my background covers the entire page. and there is no white showing at the top of the page?

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgayI.jpg)

For a Live preview visit http://www.Trillumonopoly.com

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo= sha512-2e8qq0ETcfWRI4HJBzQiA3UoyFk6tbNyG+qSaIBZLyW9Xf3sWZHN/lxe9fTh1U45DpPf07yj94KsUHHWe4Yk1A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="js/pushmenu.js"></script>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <!--BOTTOM MENU 3d-->
 <style>
/* basic menu styles */
.block-menu {
display: block;
background: transparent; 
}

.block-menu li {
display: inline-block;
}

.block-menu li a {
color: #666;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif !important;
font-smoothing: antialiased;
text-transform: uppercase;
overflow: visible;
line-height: 18px;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 15px 10px;
}

/* animation domination */
.three-d {
perspective: 200px;
transition: all .07s linear;
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
}
/* complete the animation! */
.three-d:hover .three-d-box, 
.three-d:focus .three-d-box {
    transform: translateZ(-25px) rotateX(90deg);
}

.three-d-box {
transition: all .3s ease-out;
transform: translatez(-25px);
transform-style: preserve-3d;
pointer-events: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

/* 
put the "front" and "back" elements into place with CSS transforms, 
specifically translation and translatez
*/
.front {
transform: rotatex(0deg) translatez(25px);
}

.back {
transform: rotatex(-90deg) translatez(25px);
color: #ffe7c4;
}

.front, .back {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: GoldenRod;
padding: 17px 10px;
color: white;
pointer-events: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style> 
<style>
body { padding-bottom: 70px !important; 
   font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif !important;
}

</style>
<style>
.navbar-fixed-bottom{bottom:0;margin-bottom:0;border-width:5px 0 0;    height:65px !important; border-top-color:Orange  !important; background-color:Black  !important;};</style>

<style> html { 
background: url(images/background.jpg) fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pushmenu.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="container-fluid">
 <div class="menu">

  <!-- Menu icon -->
  <div class="icon-close">
    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/close.png">
  </div>

  <!-- Menu -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


    <div id="contentarea">
    </div>
</div>  


  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom ">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 icon-menu">
        <center><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span>   </center>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">
<ul class="block-menu" id="navmenu">
<li><a href="/" class="three-d menu_nav" >
    Home
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
        <span class="front">Home</span>
        <span class="back">Home</span>
    </span>
</a></li>
<li><a href="/demos" class="three-d menu_nav">
    Artist
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
        <span class="front">Roster</span>
        <span class="back">Roster</span>
    </span>
</a></li>

<li><a href="pages/order.html" class="three-d menu_nav">
    Labels
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
        <span class="front">Labels</span>
        <span class="back">Labels</span>
    </span>
</a></li>
<li><a href="/" class="three-d menu_nav">
    Music
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
        <span class="front">Music</span>
        <span class="back">Music</span>
    </span>
</a></li>
<li><a href="/" class="three-d menu_nav">
    Videos
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
        <span class="front">Videos</span>
        <span class="back">Videos</span>
    </span>
</a></li>
<li><a href="/" class="three-d menu_nav">
    Store
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
        <span class="front">Store</span>
        <span class="back">Store</span>
    </span>
</a></li>
<li><a href="/" class="three-d menu_nav">
    Services
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
        <span class="front">Services</span>
        <span class="back">Services</span>
    </span>
</a></li>
```

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2"> SOCIAL MEDIA LINKS HERE</div>

</div>
</div>
</nav>

<script src="js/nav.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/minicart/3.0.6/minicart.min.js"></script>
<script>
paypal.minicart.render();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the padding, which I would say don't, you could also add this to your body element styles.

```
margin-top: -70px;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
padding-bottom: 70px !important;
```

on your `body`. Remove that and the white bar will go away. Here is the CSS from your code that is causing the white bar:

```
body { padding-bottom: 70px !important; 
   font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the padding from the body:

```
body {
    font-family: "Fjalla One",sans-serif !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```